# If statement set variable but syntax error

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I'm getting a syntax error with this statement

```
$catlist = if (function_exists('put_cat_icons')) {
put_cat_icons( wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id.'&echo=0'));
} else {
wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id);
}​​​​​​​
```

If I remove `$catlist =` I get no errors. What's the problem in the code? Can I set a variable like this?

Answer (score 1):

`if` as value of an assigment is invalid. Don#t know, where you get this from. However, you can use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison#language.operators.comparison.ternary) here

```
$catlist = function_exists('put_cat_icons')
    ? put_cat_icons( wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id.'&echo=0'))
    : wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id);
```

Also, when you look at your code, you may realized, that the `wp_list_categories()`-call is the same in both cases

```
$catlist = wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id);
if (function_exists('put_cat_icons')) $catlist = put_cat_icons($catlist);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest rearranging your code a little

```
if (function_exists('put_cat_icons')) {
    $catlist = put_cat_icons( wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id.'&echo=0'));
} else {
    $catlist = wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id);
}​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign to the result of a condition - they must be freestanding. Possibly you meant:

```
if (function_exists('put_cat_icons')) {
    $catlist = put_cat_icons( wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id.'&echo=0'));
} else {
    $catlist = wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id);
}​​​​​​​
```

You may have got confused between ordinary and ternary conditions, the latter of which do allow assignment.

```
$something = 1 < 2 ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you are mixing an ordinary if statement with the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) which should look something like this `$someVar = (condition) ? "TRUE VALUE" : "FALSE VALUE";`

Using the ternary operator in your case would look something like this:

```
$catlist = (function_exists('put_cat_icons')) ? 
    put_cat_icons( wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id.'&echo=0')) : 
    wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont this that is the correct way to set a variable. Are your trying to do this

```
$catlist = (function_exists('put_cat_icons')) ? put_cat_icons( wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id.'&echo=0')):
wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&show_count=1&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id);
```